# Inserting data from a list into table

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to iterate through a list and insert into a database.

```vb
Dim fields() As String
Using cnn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(conn)
  cnn.Open()
  Using insertTrans As SqlTransaction = cnn.BeginTransaction
    Using cmd As SqlCommand = cnn.CreateCommand()
      'create command
      cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [matrixtest].[dbo].[SM_Fatca_GinList] " _
                      & "(gincode, ginname, country) VALUES (@gin, @name, @country)"
      Dim gin As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@gin", SqlDbType.VarChar)
      Dim companyName As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar)
      Dim country As SqlParameter = New SqlParameter("@country", SqlDbType.VarChar)
      cmd.Parameters.Add(gin)
      cmd.Parameters.Add(companyName)
      cmd.Parameters.Add(country)
      'skip 1st row
      Dim firstRow As Boolean = True
      For Each item As String In lines
        If Not firstRow Then
          fields = item.Split("__||__")
          If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(fields(0)) Then
            If Not fields(0).Length = 0 Then
              'set parameters
              gin.Value = fields(0)
              companyName.Value = fields(1)
              country.Value = fields(2)
              cmd.Transaction = insertTrans
              cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End If
          End If
        End If
        firstRow = False
      Next
    End Using
  End Using
End Using
```

But my code is just continuing to run forever and checking in SSMS the tables aren't being populated with any data. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Command object:

[image]

Comment: I don't see where you DIM `fields`, what is its type?  What is it an array of?

Comment: @TabAlleman I just added it with an edit. It's a string array.

Comment: Use a breakpoint on the ExecuteNonQuery line and peek into the command object to see what parameter values you are passing.

Comment: At some point, you should probably perform an `insertTrans.Commit()`.

Comment: Turn on Option Strict `fields = item.Split("__||__")` doesnt do what you think it does.  Examine the result (fields content and size) in debug.  See: http://i.imgur.com/CAWzL3V.jpg

Comment: Why don't you use parameterized Stored Procedure for inserting the data?

Comment: When you loaded the CSV you could parse/split the data into a List(of Foo) where Foo is `{gin, name, country}` then just loop thru that list without any gyrations to the data or even better store it in a datatable and just issue an Update

Comment: @LarsTech Your suggestion has now made it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't committing your transaction, so you will have to add:

```
insertTrans.Commit()
```

Best to do it in a Try..Catch so you can call `insertTrans.Rollback()`, if need be.